# Stuck trying to make a Blackjack game, not sure where to go after dynamically creating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm attempting to make a blackjack game. I've searched for answers to my question and although I've found some, they just confuse me. I've created various objects to represent the cards/deck, and I know how to add elements dynamically to a page using jQuery - I've managed to make it so that when you click play, 2 div elements are created for the player and 1 for the dealer, with the class 'card'. I wasn't quite sure exactly what question to ask in the title, so apologies if it's not precise enough.

However, I have absolutely no idea where to go from here. I'm thinking I have to create a div element which will hold a card object (which I don't know how to do), and then use a bunch of if/else statements about it's suit & rank to determine what numeric value it has, and also what image to display. I'm really confused by how I do this, and I can't find anything online to explain it (I found one explanation, but it went completely over my head).

Do I even need to use objects here? Could I not just create a div element and somehow make it produce a random number between 1-52, and just use this as it's value, and then for each number have a corresponding image? Most tutorials I've seen say that objects are essential in making a game like this so I'm sure I must be wrong in thinking this is also a possibility.

I know it's kind of an obscure question, but if anyone could give me some advice on how to get over this hurdle I would really, really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're asking, but this might be something:

```
function Card(id){
    this.suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"];
    this.ranks = numbers = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];
    this.id = id;
    this.div = document.getElementById(id);
    this.setName = function(){
         this.suit = this.suits[Math.random(0, 3)];
         this.rank = this.ranks[Math.random(0, 13)];
    }
    this.setImage = function(){
         this.img = "<image src='" + this.rank + "_of_" + this.suit + "'>"; //Or however you format your titles
         this.div.innerHtml = this.img;
    }
}
```

And then, make a function to create a `<div>` tag on the body with ids like `card1`, etc. Call

```
id = 'card0';
var div = Div(id); //will have things about comparisons and stuff
var card = Card(id);
card.setName();
card.setImage();
```

And you should be able to find card images online; one example being https://github.com/Innoviox/War

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So you create the Card object and make arrays for the suit and rank, which I'm with. Is there any reason you chose 'id' as the parameter? I'm also confused by this.div = .... also, why do you need the method setName, cant you just say this.suit=...?  I understand then if you make a div tag with various id's, it will make card objects with diff. suits and ranks. I don't understand the 'var div = Div(id)' though? Apologies for all the questions!

Comment: I have the setName method so that you can change it's name; if you for example want to draw a new card you can just use a pre-existing id. I chose id as the parameter because it's the HTML term for identifying an element. I don't really know what I was going for with the `var div = Div(id)` thing but maybe you will have a function that prepares a `div` element for putting a card image in.